# Catching click event while delete thumbnail

Tags: javascript, events, dom, thumbnails, fine-uploader

I slightly modified FU thumbnail template to hook a click event on it. I also display a delete button (the provided one).
The problem is that when I click on the delete button, the click event bubbles to the rest of the javascript stack.

How can I prevent the delete button to propagate the click event??
(usually you do something like event.stopPropagation()...).

Thanks for your help

Comment: Click events naturally bubble, as do most other DOM events. Why is this an issue in your web app?

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to prevent any DOM event from bubbling, simply attach an event handler to the element where you would like it to terminate and call [`stopPropagation()` on the `Event` object](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#event). For example, for a click event:

```
someElement.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
   event.stopPropagation();
});
```

The above code will not work in IE8 and older since `addEventListener` and `stopPropagation` were first introduced in IE9.